# How do languages without passive voice foreground constituents that don't stand for agents?

Tags: syntax, linguistic-typology

one: Passive voice can be used to foreground noun phrases that don't stand for agents by putting those noun phrases in subject position.   e.g., in English,

"The man bit the dog." -->  "The dog was bitten by the man."

two:  WALS (the World Atlas of Language Structures) tells us that a lot of languages lack passive voice.

https://wals.info/feature/107A#2/18.0/148.9

three:  What foregrounding strategies for noun phrases that don't stand for agents are commonly used in languages that lack passive voice?

Comment: Maybe I should limit my question to languages that a) allow passivization, and b) have nominative-accusative morpho-syntactic alignment.

Comment: I suspect "topicalization" isn't the answer you're looking for?

Comment: Ergatives? As in "the vase broke" in English; presumably they might also exist in the languages you're looking for?

Comment: [Malagasy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malagasy_language#Verbs) has a typical Austronesian setup with [Symmetrical voice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetrical_voice).

Comment: @ Draconis:  On the contrary, topicalization may be the answer for all I know.